# How do I place div\form on a responsive image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

First i'm new to responsive design.

I'm trying to convert this landing page to a responsive design:

[image]

for the image I tryed to use class `img-responsive` from bootstrap,

**But my problems is:**

1. How to place the contact form need to be insert inside the orange box that is part of the image (red frame just to point, not part of the design).
2. How do I make the image and the form i'm placing on it responsive ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to remove the orange boxes from the image, and leave just the image as a background, and everything else as markup using HTML and CSS? (ie. the orange boxes as divs, with the text and contact form inside them)

Comment: No, This is what they decided in my new job. what does it matter ? I I think it's the same thing with it or without it :-)

Comment: It matters alot, if you're able to create the orange and content using markup, then that will make it ALOT easier to optimise for responsiveness

Comment: I mean when I want to place my div the location on the image is the same and so is the markup.

Comment: Can you show us what the image you are working with looks like in it's original form?

Answer (score 0):

If it is taking 100% width on a div you can use another div inside that with position: absolute and align it where you want it (like right: 50px bottom: 50px; ). Give the parent div a position:relative to make sure it positions inside.

You can then use a percentage width or use left:50px and whatnot. And use css media queries to make it show correctly.

Another would be to use the image as a background-image and use child div with absolute position, but you might get problems getting the height correctly cross-browser.

I'm not sure what you mean by img-responsive, from what framework is that?

Comment: img-responsive = bootstrap

Comment: Than like i said, use a parent-div with `position:relative` and put your image with `class="img-responsive"` inside and a separate div with your form with `position:absolute; bottom: 50px; left:50px; right: 50px;`. And use whatever other media-queries you use to make it fit properly cross-screensize.

Comment: what about the fields and the lables in the form ? I did what you offer and in mobile view the field is getting out of the orange box.

Comment: Well if you are using a grid row (with columns inside) you could prevent that from happening. Small view should have less columns than the big ones. So rows and columns or something you make yourself with media queries to make sure the stuff doesn't go outside. Don't force pixel width in side or it might break, keep it to percentages.

Answer (score 0):

Try out something like this. you also should use col-xs-*, col-sm-* class to make responsiveness better.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div style="position:relative;width:200; height:89px; background-color:green; 
         top:54px; left:0" class="img-responsive">
           <div style="left:15px; top:54px; position:absolute;">
             <form method="post" action="">
               <input type="text" name="name"/>
               <input type="submit" name="submit" value="go"/>
             </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>


<style type="text/css">
.span12{ background-image: url('../images/video-player-background.png'); 
background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; min-height: 1024px;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution below.

```
<div clas="img-responsive" style="position: relative;">
    <img src="example.jpg"></img> <!--That image-->
    <div style="position: absolute;" height= 100%; width: 100%"></div>
```

The `div` contains everything on top of the image will change together with the image.